# What is an appropriate number of characters for various fields in a database table?

Tags: database, character, field, varchar

I'm making a database for a local non-profit, and I have a table for volunteers. I'm using the varchar data type, but what is an appropriate number of characters for each field? That is, what number should I use for the first name, last name, address, and email address?

Comment: The size of each field should be enough to hold the values in your data. We don't have your data.

Comment: Dour High Arch, thanks for the response. There's no data yet; someone is just starting a non-profit. Are there guidelines on what to allow for in names, addresses, and email addresses? For example, right now I have the email address field as VARCHAR(80). Is that enough, too much, or about right? I have googled this, but I haven't found any general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

As Dour High Arch pointed out, without the knowledge of your data (from example what langauges are the names from, wether they fit into single-byte-charset or only unicode, etc) we can only tell you estimations and guidelines.
For example the Gmail registration form accepts 60 characters of data for both first and last names. So this can be a good guess to start with. To accomodate sucha size of data, you should use the VARCHAR2(60 CHAR) format, this way you can fit in long names even if they have non-ASCII multi-byte characters.

Comment: Thanks TewWe, that helps. I will take your advice and use the varchar2 format. Thanks again.

Comment: Please note that VARCHAR2 is an Oracle specific type, and you will be fine with VARCHAR - it is the same.